# How do I fetch count of two columns for a given criteria grouped by another column?

Tags: mysql, sql

*DataBase*: [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cdd98/1)

*Query needed*: To return the number of women and men of age 25-35 years for each Insurance Company.

*My Progress*:

```
CREATE VIEW MenInAge AS
SELECT p.pname,p.pid,p.cid
FROM Patient p
WHERE p.gender = 'm' and p.age between 25 and 35;

CREATE VIEW WomenInAge AS
SELECT p.pname,p.pid,p.cid
FROM Patient p
WHERE p.gender = 'f' and p.age between 25 and 35;

CREATE VIEW MenInAgeCount AS
SELECT m.cid, COUNT(m.pid) as c
FROM MenInAge m
GROUP BY m.cid;

CREATE VIEW WomenInAgeCount AS
SELECT w.cid, COUNT(w.pid) as c
FROM WomenInAge w
GROUP BY w.cid;
```

How do I show for every InsuranceCompany.cid the WomenInAgeCount.c and the MenInAgeCount.c columns?

Comment: @Siva that is exactky what i need, tho it is a bit too advanced for me, if you could simplify it id be thankfull

Comment: You should learn right now that views are not a good technique to use for all queries. There is no need at all for view in any of teh things you showed and you are just adding unnecessary complexity and abstraction to the database which will burn you if you do this without understanding of how a database works. Views are not something a beginner should even be aware of. Someone who doesn't know how to write a join has no business using a view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Explanation*:

You have to join the tables `InsuranceCompanies` and `Patient` using the *LEFT OUTER JOIN* by joining the records on `cid` column in both tables and also apply the filter to select only patients between age **25** and **35** (including those boundary values). The *CASE* statement simply checks whether the patient is male or female and computes two different columns by assigning values of 1 if the values match and 0 if the values don't match. Finally you have to group the result by cname to fetch the count by insurance company name.

*Explanation about CASE*:

In the CASE expression, the query states WHEN gender field value is **f** assign the column *female* with the value 1. The value 1 is hard coded because it means the query found 1 row matching the gender='f' record and this also represent 1 person. You can also state ELSE 0 but it is implicit so not necessary to specify that. This CASE expression evaluates for every record in the query result. Finanlly, you will get all the rows with female column containing either 1 or 0. When you sum this column female, you will get the total number of females, the same logic goes for male column.

## With COALESCE:

`COALESCE` here replaces any NULL values with the given value in the second parameter (here in this case zero).

[**Click here to view the demo in SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cdd98/38)

*Script*:

```
SELECT              ic.cname
                ,   COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN gender = 'f' THEN 1 END), 0) female
                ,   COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN gender = 'm' THEN 1 END), 0) male 
FROM                InsuranceCompanies ic
LEFT OUTER JOIN     Patient p
ON                  p.cid = ic.cid
AND                 age BETWEEN 25 AND 35
GROUP BY            ic.cname;
```

*Output*:

```
CNAME      FEMALE MALE
---------- ------ ----
Clalit Inc    0    2
Harel Inc     2    0
```

## Without COALESCE:

[**Click here to view the demo in SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cdd98/39)

*Script*:

```
SELECT              ic.cname
                ,   SUM(CASE WHEN gender = 'f' THEN 1 END) female
                ,   SUM(CASE WHEN gender = 'm' THEN 1 END) male 
FROM                InsuranceCompanies ic
LEFT OUTER JOIN     Patient p
ON                  p.cid = ic.cid
AND                 age BETWEEN 25 AND 35
GROUP BY            ic.cname;
```

*Output*:

```
CNAME      FEMALE MALE
---------- ------ ----
Clalit Inc  NULL   2
Harel Inc     2   NULL
```

Comment: this is correct and very accurate, tho this is a lil too advanced for what i exepected, can you simplify it a bit?

Comment: we didnt speak of COALESCE in class , is there a way to not use that?

Comment: thats beautifull... THANKS! tho 1 more thing i didnt get is does this has default ELSE statement? :CASE WHEN gender = 'm' THEN 1 END

Answer (score 0):

How about a JOIN?

```
SELECT I.cname, ISNULL(W.c,0) AS WomenCount, ISNULL(M.c,0) as MenCount
FROM InsuranceCompanies AS I
LEFT JOIN MenInAgeCount AS M ON M.cid = I.cid
LEFT JOIN WomenInAgeCount AS W ON W.cid = I.cid
```

`LEFT JOIN` here in case the Men or Women view don't contain an entry for each row in the InsuranceCompanies table. The `ISNULL` is for SQL Server, but you can modify for MySQL, Oracle as needed.

Comment: @OfekRon it only needs to compile on your RDBMS. As mentioned, it's SQL Server specific, as you didn't mention your RDBMS.

Answer (score 0):

this should give you some help -

```
select count(pid) as numPatients, cid, gender
from patient
group by cid, gender
```